# why this error ora 01403 no data found at line 27?

Tags: oracle

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000

DECLARE
  MIN_ID employees.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE;
  MAX_ID employees.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE;
  J_NAME employees.JOB_ID%TYPE;
  USER_CAT employees.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE;

BEGIN

           SELECT MAX(EMPLOYEE_ID) , MIN(EMPLOYEE_ID)
           INTO     MAX_ID ,  MIN_ID
           FROM  employees;         


           FOR I IN MIN_ID..MAX_ID LOOP

           IF I = 1 THEN
             SELECT SUBSTR(JOB_ID , INSTR(JOB_ID , '_') , LENGTH(JOB_ID) )
             INTO J_NAME
             FROM EMPLOYEES
             WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = I ; 

             INSERT INTO TASK_TABLE
              VALUES ( I , J_NAME);

           ELSE

             SELECT CASE USER_CATEGORY WHEN J_NAME THEN '1'
                                                           ELSE '0' 
                                                           END AS USER_CAT
              INTO    USER_CAT
              FROM TASK_TABLE ;
             /* WHERE USER_CATEGORY LIKE J_NAME ; */

             IF USER_CAT = '0'  THEN 
                 INSERT INTO TASK_TABLE
                 VALUES ( I , J_NAME);

             ELSE

                CONTINUE;   

             END IF;

         END IF;
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(J_NAME);

    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Impossible to tell without line numbers and input data. Presumably, line 27 contains a SELECT INTO that doesn' return any data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`no_data_found` exception happens when you try to populate a variable with `select..into` syntax, but there are no rows returned from the query.

Make sure that your query returns exactly one row when using `select..into`, and handle the exceptions properly. You should also take care of `too_many_rows`, in case your query returns more than one row.

```
declare
  ln_dummy number;
begin
  select 1 into ln_dummy
  from dual
  where
    1=2;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    --Handle
  when too_many_rows then
    --Handle
  when others then
    raise;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by a SELECT/INTO clause returning no rows. 
To prevent this the best practice would be use a cursor and a loop on this cursor. By doing this way the ORA-01403 error would never show up.

Here is a little exemple using your table:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cEMPLOYEES IS
    SELECT * FROM  employees;
  vEMPLOYEES cEMPLOYEES%rowtype;

BEGIN
  OPEN cEMPLOYEES;
  LOOP 
    FETCH cEMPLOYEES INTO vEMPLOYEES;
    EXIT WHEN cEMPLOYEES%notfound;
    IF cEMPLOYEES%found THEN
      -- Here you can make your stuff, accessing columns values like cEMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID or cEMPLOYEES.JOB_ID
      INSERT INTO TASK_TABLE
          VALUES ( cEMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID , SUBSTR(cEMPLOYEES.JOB_ID , INSTR(cEMPLOYEES.JOB_ID , '_') , LENGTH(cEMPLOYEES.JOB_ID) ));
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cEMPLOYEES;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will almost certainly be one of the `SELECT INTO...`, e.g. you don't have a record in the `EMPLOYEES` table with `EMPLOYEE_ID` = 1, or there is nothing in the `TASK_TABLE`, at the time the code is reached.

You should handle this situation with an [`when NO_DATA_FOUND` exception handler](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pl_sql_plsql_select_into_clause.htm), and possibly also handle `when TOO_MANY_ROWS` at the same time.

If however you believe that it is perfectly acceptable for the `SELECT INTO` to have zero or multiple rows, then you can use an aggregate as you've done in the first `SELECT INTO`, i.e.

```
SELECT MAX(EMPLOYEE_ID) , MIN(EMPLOYEE_ID)
       INTO     MAX_ID ,  MIN_ID
       FROM  employees;
```